# Remove Drawable from a particular postion inside adapter Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Can anyone tell me how can I remove drawable from an imagview inside an adapter. I dont want to remove the item but only want to remove the drawable of that position

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

inside onBindViewHolder method of adapter use this condition (For example in third row):

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
     if(position == 3){
            holder.imageView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
     }
  }
```